# have a reference to an object inside NSTimer selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-category

i have more than 10 objects of the same object type, lets call it Car type.
in my class, for each object i need to start a NSTimer.

```
//for object 1:
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerTick:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

//for object n:
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerTick:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

[EDIT] the timers are fired separately not at the same time.

However i have only one method for the 10 objects:

```
- (void)timerTick:(NSTimer *)timer
{
//here i need the reference to the object x (car) in order to display the timer and the name of the car for instance.
}
```

how can i achieve this, please?
im thinking of subclassing NSTimer and adding a new property (car) to it.

```
CustomTimer *mytimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerTick:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
- (void)timerTick:(CustomTimer *)timer
{
NSLog(@"%@", timer.car.name);
}
```

thanks

Comment: Do you really need a timer per car?  Can't you have a single timer and then iterate over the array of cars when it fires to update them?

Comment: hi @Paulw11, actually the timers fire at different dates.

Comment: Dates or rates?  The "date" at which timing ends should be a property of your `car`.  The rate at which your timer fires should be a constant value, say every 0.2s if you are going to update the display.